# What does the 'lkid' URL parameter mean?

Tags: apex, soql

What exactly is `CF00NW0000000diSH_lkid` a reference to, in this case?

```
portfoliofunction = [
    SELECT Id, Name, Subsidiaries_On_Contract__c
    FROM Contract_Overview__c
    WHERE Contract_Overview__c.Id =
    :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CF00NW0000000diSH_lkid')
    LIMIT 1
];
```

Is it a reference to an object's Id?

Here is the full URL :

https://cs13.salesforce.com/apex/ContractTermsAllRecords?CF00NW0000000diSH=Nestle+Test+-+700&CF00NW0000000diSH_lkid=a23W0000000AGQu&scontrolCaching=1&retURL=%2Fapex%2FContract_Overview_VF%3Fid%3Da23W0000000AGQu%26sfdc.override%3D1&RecordType=012200000008d7r&ent=01I200000004XtN&save_new=1&sfdc.override=1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`00N` is the object type pertaining to Custom Fields & Relationships.

`00NW0000000diSH` is the actual field or relationship, [which you can view](https://login.salesforce.com/00NW0000000diSH?setupid=CustomObjects) from the Setup menu.

`lkid` refers to the Lookup ID of the object which will populate that field in the case of a new record.

For example, let's say you were some viewing some *Master* record and clicked *New Detail*. The URL will include `/e?CF[relationship-id]_lkid=[master-id]` and the form will be rendered with the master field pre-populated. Conversely, knowing this, you can generate and distribute links to that form.

Answer (score 4):

_LKID = lookupId

Taking just the part of the url you have posted relating to _lkid

```
?CF00NW0000000diSH=Nestle+Test+-+700&CF00NW0000000diSH_lkid=a23W0000000AGQu
```

This  `CF00NW0000000diSH` is the id of the lookup on the page, if you check it using firebug you will get this id.  `Nestle+Test+-+700` is the name of the relationship record and `CF00NW0000000diSH_lkid` this stores the relationship id of the record.

For example

assuming that you are referring to lookup on account, CF00NW0000000diSH holds the account name Nestle+Test+-+700  and CF00NW0000000diSH_lkid is holds the accountId which is a23W0000000AGQu.

Answer (score 2):

Just an extension to the answer from user320.
There are lots of infos on the net aboul lkid, check it out:

- https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Gt4QAAS
- http://force201.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/lkid-hack-value-is-fragile/
- http://www.tgerm.com/2012/02/field-id-lkid-describe.html
- http://sfswe.wordpress.com/tag/lkid/