# How to pass default value for lookup in salesforce standard view page

Tags: lookup, standard-objects

I have a lookup field in standard page. when I click on a custom button in other page need to pass the default value for lookup field in my standard page. If I pass some field id and values in url seems it work anybody have working example. Also is this approach reliable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that you need to use so-called `LKID hack` or in other words `URL hacking`. There are many infos about it and even an idea on IdeaExchange: [Replace the lkid hack](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Gt4QAAS)

The workarounf is that you need to know the field ID you want to pre-populate and use this id in the URL string in the link on your corresponding visualforce page.

Take a look at this tutorial for understanding the workaround:
[Salesforce URL Hacking to Prepopulate Fields on a Standard Page Layout](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html)

Some info about LKID at the Stackexchange Salesforce forum:
[What does the 'lkid' URL parameter mean?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11154/what-does-the-lkid-url-parameter-mean)