# Redirect to object creation from visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, custom, redirect, object

Is it possible to redirect the user to a custom object creation page from a visualforce page? If so, how can I get the URL of this creation page? And what would I need to do in the code to pass an argument with it? (eg: a custom object id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to create a pagerefence method on your controller, similar to this:

```
public PageReference customObjectPageReference() {
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = YourCustomObject__c.SObjectType.getDescribe();
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/' + R.getKeyPrefix() + '/e');
    pr.getParameters().put('Id,'theId');
    return pr;
}
```

This is taking into account that the key prefix might be different on different orgs.

Note that only a limited set of arguments can be passed this way without hardcoding field id's. There are some workarounds for this, depending on what arguments you need to pass.

Comment: Thats working, apparently. However, when I try to use this solution with a Standard User, it doesn't work. I have two record types for this object, and regular users may access only one of them (and should remain this way). When I used your solution, SF threw an error of insuficient privileges, even though the classes are allowed for this profile. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does the Standard User have 'Create' authorization on the custom object? And do you specify any parameters in the PageReference?

Comment: Nevermind! I had to allow the profile to access the vf page and the custom tab. lol Thanks! Now I do need to pass the ID to the creation page.

Comment: Which Id? Are you referring to an existing custom object record, or do you need e.g. a lookup filled with an Id?

Comment: I need to pass an existing record. Like a product id, and I already have that id. Just need to pass it to the object creation page that takes it. However, this page is not a custom page. It is the default object creation page from SF.

Comment: OK. See this post for a good overview on that: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21216/how-to-pass-default-value-for-lookup-in-salesforce-standard-view-page